# Allow typing mobile numbers starting with 7,8 or 9

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

I need the realtime validation to use in the input tag to allow user typing only the number starting with 7,8 or 9. right now I have the following thing which is not working. Only if the user types the digits 7 to 9 as the first digit on the input field then only it should be appearing in the input field.

```
<input type="tel" label="Mobile Number" pattern="^[7-9][0-9]{8}$" maxLength="10"/>
```

Comment: The `^[7-9][0-9]{8}$` pattern matches a string that starts with `7`, `8` or `9`, and then contains any 8 digits. It checks the final format, the `pattern` attribute is not usually used for live input validation. At any rate, you seem to want to use `^[7-9]\d{0,8}$` pattern.

Comment: it's still allowing to **type the number** 0-6 as first digit in the input field.

Comment: Yeah, because you need to use `type="text"` if you want `pattern` to work at all.

Comment: Define "not working". It works fine for me. https://i.imgur.com/8i5WAJk.png

Comment: I changed it's type to text from tel and used your given pattern. But it's same as before. not working..

Comment: @Quentin, It means if anybody tries to type 0 to 6 as the first digit then it shouldn't be coming in the input field.

Comment: Isn't pattern just tested on submit? It's not *real time*.

Comment: @Subhojit — I'm not aware of any browser that test patterns as you type (it would be non-trivial to do that anyway, if the field is empty and you type `3` then that is wrong and it is blocked, but if you type `7` then it is still wrong because the next character doesn't exist yet)

Comment: yeah.. I apologize.. I have edited my question.

Comment: My mobile number consists of 10 characters (not 9) after the prefix code (which I'd normally include in the number making it 12 characters starting with a +. Be **very** careful when you try to limit what you think a phone number is (or a name, or an address or a gender, or lots of other things)

Comment: `pattern` attribute is implied anchored, so `^` and `$` are unnecessary and will break your validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern on input is validated only on submit.

If you want to validate on real time, You can achieve it using javascript

```
(function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('YOUR_INPUT_ID');
    var pattern = /^[7-9][0-9]{0,8}$/;
    var value = input.value;
    !pattern.test(value) && (input.value = value = '');
    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var currentValue = this.value;
        if(currentValue && !pattern.test(currentValue)) this.value = value;
        else value = currentValue;
    });
})();
```

Comment: used it in the **onChange** function and worked like a charm.